# autorelease and retain causes message sent to deallocated message

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been getting this random crash, in which I don't know how to reproduce again. It happens when I was browsing/using the apps for some time, switching views here and there and I got this:

[image]

First of all I don't know which UIImage is this crash referring to. I do have a crash report, but I don't know how to read it. I would like to reproduce the error, but I don't know how to.. it seems that it's quite random. Can someone help me out in debugging this?

Comment: if you try in the debugger prompt the following: **gdb>** `po 0x555020`, do you see the same object (UIImage) as the cause of the error?

Comment: if you still want to read crash report, you can find instruction here: http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to reproduce the failure, it will be very hard.

If you cannot reproduce it, I would suggest building your project by using the Xcode option "Build and Analyze". Indeed, since this is seemingly a problem with retain/release, "Build and Analyze" could give you some hint at where things go bad. By the way, if you are not doing it, it is highly suggested, almost mandatory check.

You could try and post the crash report, but I doubt it will be useful. The point is finding out where the UIImage is deallocated and why, the crash report refers to an attempt to use the UIImage after its release, so this would likely be in a different portion of your code.

If you have some suspect as to which class contain this UIImage, you can post some code so that we can help you inspect it.

As a hopefully useful hint as to how to reproduce this issue, I would also suggest sending the simulator a Memory Warning. Indeed, in such cases all UIViews that are not displayed are released and this could be the culprit with your UIImage. So, you send it and see if the crash happens again... just a hint, anyway...

Comment: I think he already has NSZombieEnabled since it does not say Exc_BAD_ACCESS, and shows exactly what he is trying to retain.

Comment: @Cyprian, yeah, that's right... thanks! removed from my answer.

Comment: well my best guess would be at TTImageView. I have this inside my UITableViewCell, but I don't want to mess around with Three20's source code.

Comment: I don't think that three20 has got problems in its implementation, but you can never know... anyway, I would start by inspecting your data source and above all your model... if you provide some code...

Comment: Have you used autorelease in your class where is that crashing right now .If yes just try to remove that autorelease(for time being) and test it once again .Hope this helps.

Comment: will try that and see what happens, I have an autorelease in the TTImageView

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say something for sure. This is my guess.

I see you are getting some data from an external source "convore.com". When you say you get the error randomly, I think it may be due to the data received from the convore.com api. Probably from time to time you are not getting the image, link, or graphics from the server and you don't create and image, and then you are trying to retain it, causing the error.